# Javascript keycode catching non-latin characters? (Also need to work in selectize.js)

Tags: javascript, selectize.js

Is it possible to catch non latin characters in Javascript using keycode? I want to catch Turkish characters like "ü, ş, ö, ğ, ı and İ". I am using a plugin called selectize.js to turn select box into auto-complete search. This plugin uses Javascript keyCode to detect what is pressed but Turkish characters are not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this sample to catch those characters:

```js
$(document.body).keypress(function(e) {
  
  var
    letter = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode); // or e.which
  
  if (['ü', 'ş', 'ö', 'ğ', 'ı', 'İ'].indexOf(letter) !== -1) {
    
    alert('Yay! Letter: "' + letter + '" detected');
  }
  
  $('#text').text(letter);
});
```

```css
body {
  
  background-color: #BDE3F0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="text">Click here and press any key on the keyboard!</span>
```

Greetings from Azerbaijan :)

Comment: Thanks! Greeting from Turkey! ^^